# How to get the Bootstrap form-fields horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried all the possible ways but I could not get the fields horizontally aligned.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acctName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account Name </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.acctName" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Account Name" />
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acctId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.acctId" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Account ID" />
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also tried

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acctName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account Name </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.acctName" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Account Name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acctId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.acctId" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Account ID" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Still, the fields appear stacked vertically.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you need form horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @ManishPatel Horizontal.

Comment: you can use `<form class="form-inline"></form>`

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="acctName" class="control-label">Account Name </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" ng-model="vm.acctName" placeholder="Account Name" />     
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="acctId" class="control-label">Account ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" ng-model="vm.acctId"  placeholder="Account ID" />      
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">        
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be invalid use of classes. Try the following code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="acctName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Account Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="acctName" ng-model="vm.acctName" placeholder="Account Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="acctId" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Account ID</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" id="acctId" ng-model="vm.acctName" placeholder="Account ID" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```